# Lifting a metric on the base space to the principal $U(1)$ bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

"Let $π:P→M$ be a $U(1)$-principal bundle. We may lift any metric $m$ on $M$ to a $U(1)$-invariant metric $\widehat{m}$ on P such that $π_∗\widehat{m}=m$."

I found a more general form of the above statement in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372424/lifting-a-metric-on-a-principal-bundle-with-non-compact-fibre. Could anyone tell me what the name of this theorem is? Any reference is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this theorem has any particular name (it's a fairly simple construction), although I've occasionally seen the metric referred to as the "Kaluza-Klein metric", since the U(1)-version can be used to construct a Hamiltonian that reproduces the motion of a charged particle in an magnetic field (i.e. the Lorentz force equation - the nonabelian version is called Wong's equation). If you're looking for some specific references to the definition of this metric, you could try ["Canonical formulations of a classical particle in a Yang-Mills field and Wong's equations"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00420042)
 Section 2 or ["A Tour of Subriemannian Geometries, Their Geodesics and Applications"](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-91-s)
 Chapter 11 (both by Richard Montgomery), or ["Riemannian Geometry, Fiber Bundles, Kaluza-Klein Theories and All That..."](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/0488) Chapter 4 by Coquereaux and Jadczyk. I'm sure there are plenty of other references out there.